# Since Biblical Unitarians deny the deity of Jesus Christ how do they understand or explain 1 John 3:2?

Tags: unitarianism

1 John 3:2 from the NASB. "Beloved, now we are the children of God, and it has not appeared as yet what we shall be. We know that when He appears, we shall be like Him, because we shall see Him just as He is."

Please notice the four pronouns in the last sentence, "He" "Him" "Him" "He." To whom do they refer?

Comment: Not a Unitarian - but I suppose the response would be that it’s like God.

Comment: Or Jesus. Everyone agrees we will be like Jesus. I'm not sure what you think the relevance of Unitarianism is to this verse.

Comment: @curiousdannii The relevance I think is pretty obvious . They admit they are "Biblical" Unitarians which means they use the Bible. I gave a verse in the Bible and am asking them to "exegete" the verse and explain who do the pronouns refer to? Or to put it another way, is Jesus identified as God in the verse? If not why not?

Comment: Personally, I would have thought it better to ask a question about the text on SE-BH and seek clarification of the exact meaning of the wording. I would view that, myself, as more edifiying.

Comment: @Nigelj Thanks for the advice but I just didn't think of it that way. I find it interesting that I'm getting negative votes here and on my other thread about the Jehovah's Witnesses teaching Jesus is "a god." I must be doing something right since there is nothing but "crickets" on these two threads. Thanks again!

Comment: The text is notable and has similar content to 1 Timothy 3:16 _God manifest in flesh_ (TR/KJV) which of course is removed in the 1881 W&H Greek text for reasons which Hermon Hoskier makes clear in his rebuttal of the 1881 text : _Codex B and its Allies_. 1 John 3:2 also points to _if God be manifested, we shall be like him (also)_. Again, the one 'manifested' is Jesus Christ and he is termed 'God'. My point was to examine the text without bias (on SE-BH) rather than focus on controversy.